# Overloading subscript operator not working as expected

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, subscript, subscript-operator

I have a `String` struct that I overloaded the subscript operator on. But it doesn't seem to work.

```cpp
//my_string.h

struct String {
    char* Text;
    uint64 Length;

    char& operator[](int32 index); 
}
```

```cpp
//my_string.cpp

char& String::operator[](int32 index) {
    ASSERT(index >= 0);
    return Text[index];
}
```

```cpp
//main.cpp

String* test = string_create("Hello world");
char c = test[0];
```

Visual Studio gives me the following error:

> no suitable conversion function from "String" to "char" exists

Comment: `test` is a pointer to String, not a String. Therefore the *overloaded* subscript operator doesn't apply.

Comment: I suggest moving the implementation of `string_create` to a constructor of `String` and deleting the function entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler issued an error because in this statement

```
char c = test[0];
```

the expression `test[0]` has the type `String`.

In this declaration

```
String* test = string_create("Hello world");
```

you declared a pointer instead of an object of the type String.

If it is not a typo then in this case you have to write

```
char c = ( *test )[0];
```

or

```
char c = test->operator []( 0 );
```

Also it looks strange that the data member `Length` has the type `uint64`

```
uint64 Length;
```

while the index used in the operator has the type `int32`.